# Sorting a Swift array of object by mixture of NSDate and String times

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have an array of objects which has a startDate property of type NSDate, and a property of stateTime, which is a string.

The issue I'm have is that startDate considers the month, day, and year, but not time. I'm making the NSDate from an endpoint that return a date in this format: "2015-10-01T00:00:00.000Z".

startTime is represented as a string with the format of "8:00 AM".

I'm a bit lost on how to convert this all to a NSDate object to do a sort comparison.

I'm mostly comfortable with Swift and anyone can offer some help.

Thanks

Comment: Check out `NSDateComponents`. NSHipster has a nice article on it... http://nshipster.com/nsdatecomponents/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this work around.
First convert you array to string.

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" //format style. Browse online to get a format that fits your needs.
 var dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(startDate)
 var completeDate = dateString+ startTime
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(completeDate)
```

Then use date for the comparsion.